# How to access json response to jquery autocomplete inside and outside of jquery autocomplete?

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui, jquery

Here is the response I'm getting back (it's working):

```
{"matches":[
  {"_core_product_id":"648","finish":"Distressed Green\/Antique Bronze","COUNT(*)":"1"},
  {"_core_product_id":"157","finish":"Nightingale Green","COUNT(*)":"1"}],
"count":2}
```

I want to display each category category and COUNT(*) in the dropdown select. I have no immediate need, but I will likely want and to use the the _core_product_id somewhere else, outside of the autocomplete field.

Here is my autocomplete jquery code:

```
.autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
        $.getJSON( 'controllers/clean/ajax/search.php', {
            'fieldid_tableid_type' : this.element[0].id,
            'term': extractLast( request.term )
        //}, response(['red', 'green', 'blue']) );
        }, 
        response );
    },
    search: function() {
        // custom minLength
        var term = extractLast( this.value );
        if ( term.length < 2 ) {
            return false;
        }
    },
    focus: function() {
        // prevent value inserted on focus
        return false;
    },
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        var terms = split( this.value );
        // remove the current input
        terms.pop();
        // add the selected item
        terms.push( ui.item.value );
        // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
        terms.push( '' );
        this.value = terms.join( '| ' );
        return false;
    },
    delay: 750
});
```

I can't figure out where to put "response" and how to use it. Any help would be great. I know there are other questions (a lot) about this but I haven't found one that solves my problem yet. Thanks.

I notice that the jquery ui documentation shows the response being used just inside of autocomplete. Whereas some examples show it other places (just inside of source, for example).
jQuery UI documentation: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-response

Answer (score 0):

The `response` is a callback function, to which you need to pass the the remotely loaded values

```
.autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
        response($.getJSON( 'controllers/clean/ajax/search.php', {
            'fieldid_tableid_type' : this.element[0].id,
            'term': extractLast( request.term )
            //}, response(['red', 'green', 'blue']) );
        }));
    },
    search: function() {
        // custom minLength
        var term = extractLast( this.value );
        if ( term.length < 2 ) {
            return false;
        }
    },
    focus: function() {
        // prevent value inserted on focus
        return false;
    },
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        var terms = split( this.value );
        // remove the current input
        terms.pop();
        // add the selected item
        terms.push( ui.item.value );
        // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
        terms.push( '' );
        this.value = terms.join( '| ' );
        return false;
    },
    delay: 750
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. But I don't understand where/how the json response is parsed and put into the dropdown. Can you explain/show? Also, I notice where you put response is different than where I put it. But the weird thing is that I have another jquery Autocomplete that works using the same exact code (but response json is formatted differently).